# Was Falkor influenced by East Asian dragons?

Tags: inspiration, dragons, the-neverending-story

Falkor reminds me of East Asian [dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_dragon), in terms of his appearance and being a luck dragon. But I only see a mention that it has been [drawn to look like one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Neverending_Story_characters#Falkor). I'm wondering about clear influences or just coincidences.

Comment: Do you mean Falcor in the book, or Falcor in the movie?

Comment: I never read the book, info about either or both is cool.

Comment: FWIW, in the book, he was even more like an Asian dragon, being leonine rather than canine in appearance. I've seen a few mentions of Ende (the author of the book) saying that Falkor is meant to look like an Asian dragon, but I haven't found an actual quote by him saying as much.